Get data from qrCode inside Uint8List (Image) in flutter
I'm developping a web app using flutter, the app is a kind of video conferencing using LiveKit (webrtc).
I try to add the following feature: onclick on Live video widget, I want to scan if there is QrCode data and show that data.
I display live video using:
VideoTrackRenderer(
  fit: RTCVideoViewObjectFit.RTCVideoViewObjectFitCover,
  widget.videoTrack,
),

I have the ability to get the current frame using:
await videoTrack.mediaStreamTrack.captureFrame();
The problem is that I don't find any package to scan image that's not from local storage...
Second possibility is to get video stream and scan it using a qrcode scanning package but also I don't find any that accept other stream than camera...
